# Что значит @$someVar

Tags: php

Что означает запись @$someVar. Интересует запись @$. Подскажете где почитать.

Отрывок кода:

```
$arr= array_merge(range(0,9),range("A","Z"));

for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)

{
    $ch = $arr[array_rand($arr)];

    @$captcha=$captcha.$ch;

    @$fc=$fc.$ch.",";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [оператор управления ошибками](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php), советую его избегать и никогда не использовать, очень плохая практика.

Если коротко, то не говорит об ошибках, когда они происходят, вот что говорит документация:

> В случае, если он предшествует какому-либо выражению в PHP-коде, любые
> сообщения об ошибках, генерируемые этим выражением, будут
> проигнорированы.

Comment: Понял! Огромное спасибо!